# getline() a string giving difficulty

Tags: c++

i am doing a task where i am inputting ist no of times you want to have input and then i am inputting a full line by the use of getline but sime how i am not able to do that.

here when i try to input '1' as my no. of test cases it instantly gives '0' as answer and out of the loop why is not this cin>> test; here compatible with getline (cin,s);

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test,j; 
    cin>>test;

    int len;
    string s;       
    for(j=1;j<=test;j++)
    { 
        getline( cin,s);
        len = s.length();
        cout<<len;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

the difficulty

```
input :
1
output:
0

expected
input:
1
Hello World
output
11
```

Well I mixed a little C to get My answer

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int test,j; 
    scanf("%d\n",&test);

    int len;
    string s;       
    for(j=1;j<=test;j++)
    { 
        getline( cin,s);
        len = s.length();
        cout<<len;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz: he meant it as input.

Comment: hey Hello World is my input string not output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing formatted input and unformatted input functions.

`operator>>` leaves the trailing newline after the number you extracted in the input buffer, but this isn't a problem for subsequent reads done with `operator>>` because it skips all the whitespace it finds before reading. On the other hand, `getline` reads until it finds the delimiter (`\n` by default) without skipping anything.

Long story short: if you want to use `getline` you have to clean the buffer from the `\n` after your `cin>>test;`:

```
#include <limits>
// ...

cin>>test;
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: can you give me a web-link from where i could understand the problem
or is there any other way to do what i suppose to do in c++ without using limits

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html , this explains the problem with respect to C. I generally solve this by reading the '\n' to a character before calling getline (or fgets in C)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j=1;j<=test;j++)     
{          
getline( cin,s);         
len = s.length();         
cout<<len;      
}
```

This is reading in the int and the string with the one carridge return.

It reads 1 as the total and then nothing as the string (hence the length of 0).
Try 1TEST and this should give you a length of 4.

Comment: Nope, if you notice he wrote the test as `j<=test`, not `j<test`. It's unusual in C++ but correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is you are giving input stream as a parameter where you should give buffer.
Try this.

```
{  
    char szInput[256];  
    cin.getline( szInput,256);  
    len = strlen(szInput);  
    cout<<len;  
}
```